# NodeJS - readline calback loops itself

Tags: javascript, node.js

A readline callback is supposed to execute after it runs the question right? But if I pass a string to make it look like an input, then the second question doesn't execute at all.

```
rl.question(questions[answers.length], questionAnswered; // Works fine. Asks all question.

node .\questions.js
What is your name? test
1
Where do you live? test
2
What are you going to do with nodejs? test3
3
Thanks for the answers!!
[ 'test', 'test', 'test3' ]
```

Passing 'test' as input doesn't work as expected. I was expecting that it'll still ask the question.

```
rl.question(questions[answers.length], questionAnswered('test')); // Will not ask second and third question.

node .\questions.js
What is your name? test
1
2
3
Thanks for the answers!!
[ 'test', 'test', 'test' ]
```

Here is the complete code:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});


const questions = [
    "What is your name? ",
    "Where do you live? ",
    "What are you going to do with nodejs? "
];



const createQuestions = (questions, done) => {

    const answers = [];
    const [firstQuestion] = questions;

    questionAnswered = (answer) => {

        answers.push(answer);
        console.log(answers.length);
        if (answers.length < questions.length) {
        console.lol(answers.length);
            rl.question(questions[answers.length], questionAnswered; // Works fine. Asks all question.
            rl.question(questions[answers.length], questionAnswered('test')); // Will not ask second question.
        } else {
            done(answers);
        }

    };

    rl.question(firstQuestion, questionAnswered);

};

createQuestions(questions, answers => {
    console.log("Thanks for the answers!!");
    console.log(answers);
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't call itself. *You* call it. `questionAnswered` is a callback *function*, `questionAnswered('test')` is not.

Comment: Btw, `rl.question(questions[answers.length], questionAnswered()` is a syntax error. Did you mean `rl.question(questions[answers.length], questionAnswered)`?

Comment: yea I meant `questionAnswered` not `questionAnswered()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use factory pattern for your `questionAnswered` function.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});


const questions = [
  "What is your name? ",
  "Where do you live? ",
  "What are you going to do with nodejs? "
];



const createQuestions = (questions, done) => {

  const answers = [];
  const [firstQuestion] = questions;

  questionAnswered = (defaultAnswer) => {

    return function (answer) {
      if (defaultAnswer) {
        answers.push(defaultAnswer);
      }
      else {
        answers.push(answer);
      }
      if (answers.length < questions.length) {

        rl.question(questions[answers.length], questionAnswered('test'));

      }
      else {

        done(answers);

      }
    };
  };

  rl.question(firstQuestion, questionAnswered());

};

createQuestions(questions, answers => {
  console.log('---->', answers);
  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: I never thought it had a workaround but I was curious about why it happened.  @Bergi comment explained that bit. Thanks again